# How to draw the contour plot of $\frac{\ln(1-|x|-|y|)}{xy}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to draw the cantour plot of the function:$\frac{\ln(1-|x|-|y|)}{xy}$.

How I started:

$$e^{zxy}= 1-|x|-|y|$$

However now I got completely lost, since I cannot get the equation into a form that I would know how to draw. If we just look at the integers $0,1$.

So for $z = 0$:

$$ 0 = |x| - |y| \iff |y| = |x|$$

For $z = 1$ (I dont know what to do here):
$$e^{xy} = 1-|x|-|y|$$

Comment: Let $y$ be a set of numbers, then draw the 2d plots for each case. The same can be done for $x$ too.

Comment: @TymaGaidash But we have $f(x,y) = \frac{\ln(1-|x|-|y|)}{xy}$. How do you expect to do that ?